# Gradle Sync issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Out of no where, my project shows the message

```
Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync might be necessary for the IDE to work properly
```

With the link "Sync now" after it. (Although I haven't edited the gradle file)

However, no matter how many times I click on Sync now, rebuild the project, or make it, it just display s the same message again, and it shows:

```
Grade build finished in 3s ...etc
```

and when I check the log it just says Gradle sync completed.
I can't run the project either, cause it just shows the target device and that's it.

I have also tried to remove the .idea folder which didn't affect

EDIT:
my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.evently.pianomar.evently"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
}
```

Comment: Show your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Then you should select the target device

Comment: I have edited my question to include build.gradle

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi What I meant was that after I select the targeted device, it says in the console or "Run" : Target device: Nexus 6p etc....

Comment: In order to run/debug you need a real device connected to your system or an emulator

Comment: I understand, my device IS connected, I have ran the project many times before, but the message 

"Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync might be necessary for the IDE to work properly"

Persists and when I click run, there are no errors, it just does not run

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The message is still there..

Comment: *it just shows the target device and that's it* Means ? you couldn't run the project is it ? can you post screenshot of that ?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue and here's how I solved it: I noticed my time and date were incorrect, so I updated them and then rebuilt the project and it worked!